# Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments. (src/router/index.ts)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using `Vue.js` with `Quasar Framework`, and have not gone further to create components due to the error below. I have tried this solution: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9657 in my code, but still not working.

> Untyped function calls may not accept type

```
Version: typescript 4.2
```

This is the file where the issue is caused.

`src/router/index.ts`

```js
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { Store } from 'vuex';
import { StateInterface } from '../store';
import routes from './routes';

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Router instantiation
 */

export default route<Store<StateInterface>>(function ({ Vue } : {Vue: any}) {
  Vue.use(VueRouter);

  const Router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,

    // Leave these as is and change from quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
  });

  return Router;
})
```

Would you let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: What line does the error refer to? How do you use `route`?

Comment: @EstusFlask The error refers to the line 12. This router has made automatically when I created this vue app..